# docker api is not showing memoryReservation value when run in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-api

I have specified memory limit and request when starting the containers in kubernetes.

```
resources:

   limits:
      memory: 500Mi
   requests:
      memory: 200Mi
```

When i do "kubernetes describe nodes", i am able to see the limits,

```
Non-terminated Pods:         (5 in total)
Namespace                  Name                                CPU 
Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
---------                  ----                                -------- 
-- 
--  ----------  ---------------  -------------
kube-system                calico-node-qqx4j                   250m (12%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
kube-system                kube-proxy-6fdhg                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
test                       replicaset1-452-9zcn8               100m (5%)     500m (25%)  200Mi (2%)       500Mi (6%)
test                       replicaset1-452-fpv5p               100m (5%)     500m (25%)  200Mi (2%)       500Mi (6%)
ma                         replicaset1-452-x7nv5               100m (5%)     500m (25%)  200Mi (2%)       500Mi (6%)
```

But when i do docker inspect, i can see only "Memory limit" value, and not "Memory reservation".

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X GET http:/v1.24/containers/b81333392dda/json | grep -i memory

"Memory":524288000
"MemoryReservation":0
```

Memory reservation value is showing as 0 in docker-api.

Comment: Why did you decide that they are connected?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev What is the equivalent of requested memory resource?